# Appengine ID/Name vs WebSafeKey

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When writing the endpoints in java, for finding items by their keys, should I use the **Id** or the **webSafeString** of the key? In what situations does this matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's up to you.

- Do the entities have parents? Then you probably want to use the `urlsafe` representation as a single string will contain the full path to the entity. If you used an ID instead - you would somehow need to manually include the IDs of all parents up to the root.
- No parents & IDs are numeric / alphanumeric? Then just use the IDs as they look cleaner (again, this is not a rule and is completely up to you).
- No parents but IDs have special characters in them? Use the `urlsafe` representation as you might have issues with not being able to use some special characters without encoding them in HTTP.
- Note #1: the `urlsafe` representation have the entity names encoded that can be easily decoded, this is unlikely a privacy issue but you still should be aware of it. The actual data (IDs) are also simply encoded and can be easily decoded, so be careful when you use personal information such as emails as IDs, they are not safe with `urlsafe`.
- Note #2: if you decide to change the structure of your data in the future (parents <-> children), you might get stuck with some `urlsafe` data you issued to your users who are not aware of the changes you might have done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But if the information can be decoded from the websafekey, isn't there another more secure way to retrieve entities by keys/ids? Or a way to make it more difficult to decoded the information passed to the queries?

Comment: IDs are normally randomly generated and thus don't really contain any sensetive information so there's no need to encrypt them but if you're worried your `urlsafe`s reveal sensetive information then simply encrypt them before transfering to the user and decrypt when getting back with a secret key that's only known to your app.

Comment: Awesome write up. Could you clarify what you mean by Note #2?

Comment: @MicroR yes, although the key you provided seems somewhat incomplete - it's still just a slightly modified base64 encoding (NOT encryption) which can be easily decoded by anyone.

Note #2 I meant that your app name, your parent/child info - all encoded in the urlsafe string and if any of it is to change in the future - you may have, say, broken links if you were to use urlsafes in URLs.