# Allocate a random Id to use in Entity constructor Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

When you insert an Entity into datastore with a `@id Long id;` property, the datastore automatically creates a random (or what seems like a random) Long value as the id that looks like: `5490350115034675`.

I would like to set the `Long` id myself but have it be randomly generated from datastore.

I found this piece of code that seems to do just that:

```
 Key<MyEntity> entityKey = factory().allocateId(MyEntity.class);
 Long commentId = entityKey.getId();
```

Then I can pass in the `commentId` into the constructor of `MyEntity` and subsequently save it to the datastore.

When I do that however, I do not seem to get a randomly generated id, it seems to follow some weird pattern where the first allocated id is `1` and the next one is `10002`, then `20001` and so on.

Not sure what all that means and if it is safe to continue using... Is this the only way to do this?

Comment: And why do you want random ids?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Seems like the right thing to do? =P Are you saying it shouldn't matter?

Comment: @MicroR You don't want random ids *jediwave* you want safe and unused ids. Also allocateId isn't random, it's a datastore functionality that gives you a safe-to-use id for your entity. So it's safe to use. That pattern you see comes from the datastore because it usually allocates whole blocks of ids. It will look different in the live environment.

Comment: @konqi I don't want random ids. I want safe and unused ids.

Comment: @konqi The datastore automatically generates a random ID for an Entity saved into the datastore. What about if that Entity has a Parent? Will the auto-generated ID be unique to all Kinds? Or are IDs guaranteed to be unique only across kinds with the same parent Entity? I deleted parts of my test database but I could have sworn the latter was the case when looking at the Entities stored in my database.

Comment: If there's a parent, the datastore has a different allocation method (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#allocateIds-com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key-java.lang.String-long-) Objectify possibly has a similar method in the factory. I don't think the id will be unique across all Kinds. I'd even go so far and say that the same id is possible for the same Kind if the Parent is different. But honestly - I don't know. Does it matter though? If you generate a key like that, the key is always unique, which is all that matters.

Comment: That is an interesting question though. Maybe search whether it was asked before and, if not, ask it.

Comment: @konqi Yeah I think the same id is possible for the same kind if the parent is different. The key is indeed all that matters. I was just wondering if doing a filter query on an ID of a Entity that has a Parent would be a bad idea and it seems like it is.

Comment: @MicroR It also wouldn't work since (by default) only the whole key is indexed - not the local entity id. If you try, the result should come back empty.

Comment: @konqi Right. Unless you manually index that property. So how should I query for all Entities that have no parent? For example, let's say a `User'`s `Post`s (but `Post` does not have `User` as `@Parent`). Should I just filter like this: `q = q.filter("userKey =", userKey);`? Where I store the `userKey` as an indexed property in the `Post`?

Comment: Exactly like that. Although you could omit the `=` since that is the default. and `userKey` would have to be either `Key<User>` or `Ref<User>` using objectify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine allocates IDs using its own internal algorithm designed to improve datastore performance. I would trust App Engine team to do their magic.

Introducing your own scheme for allocating IDs is not as simple - you have to account for eventual consistency, etc. And it's unlikely that you will gain anything, performance-wise, from all this effort.

Comment: So you are saying my code ` Key<MyEntity> entityKey = factory().allocateId(MyEntity.class);` is safe to use then and won't conflict anything (e.g. give me an ID already in the datastore or allocated somewhere else in the program)?

Comment: It is both safe and unnecessary :)  You should have a specific reason to allocate IDs ahead of time. Otherwise, simply create an entity, and the Datastore will give it a safe ID which is guaranteed to be unique for this entity kind within an entity group.

Comment: The reason I want to allocate IDs is because when I create my Entity, I want to pass in the ID into the constructor. Why? Because I want to use that ID to create the websafeKey inside the constructor and save it as a property of the Entity. Why? This is the structure of my Entities that have parents or grandparents. Makes it easier to create/get/delete Entities that have parents, grandparents. ---This is the only way I could think of doing that, because like you said, the Datastore will give an Entity an ID, but ONLY after you save it. This saves one extra save step.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any benefits in your approach. Every key already has information about all parents, grandparents, etc. So you can just pass a key as a reference - then getting/deleting entities is super-easy. And you did not save any steps as you have to allocate an ID before you create an entity.

Comment: My question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860123/how-to-create-api-methods-in-google-app-engine-that-have-several-decedents-ances explains the problem I have in more detail. The conclusion I came to was to use websafeKey's as parameters in my API methods. I found it more convenient to store the websafeKey of each Entity in a property field of that same entity. The step I save is that I save having to save the entity again to the datastore after I update it's ID.

Comment: @MicroR storing the websafe key for each entity seems completely redundant since the websafeKey and the entity key itself are the same and can be converted into each other. Actually i wanted to give you an example for when to use pre-allocated Ids: It's very useful if you create multiple entities with references between each other and saving them in a single transaction. If you were not to use pre-allocated ids in such a case, you would have to save the entity, use the returned key and use that as a reference. I try to avoid the latter by using allocated ids.

Comment: @konqi How is it redundant? Let's say my ancestry looks like this: `User->Post->Comment`. Now let's say I need to create a new `Comment` on a `Post`.I need to know the Key of the `Post`. With my method, I can just pass in the `Post` or get it's `myPost.getWebsafeKey()`. Without all that, I would also need to pass in the User entities ID, and the Post ID just to generate the key to that `Post`. By storing the `Post`'s websafeKey as a property I can skip having to figure out what the `User`'s ID was.

Comment: Instead of passing 3 numbers, you pass a very long string (websafeKey) which includes these 3 numbers. Typically, you would simply pass Comment entity which includes Post ID and User ID, if necessary, using simple JSON. No need for this extra complexity.

Comment: In addition to what Andrei said, if your `Post` has a `Ref<User>` or `User` is an ancestor of `Post` then you have the Id of the parent already in those. If you store the websafe key in addition this information is redundant and you should avoid that, since if you ever forget to update either you're in for trouble (been there, done that, had to restore from backup).

Comment: @konqi , {at} Andrei Volgin - But what if I am calling my API methods from inside an Android or iPhone app? I am not sure I can pass in an Entity with both platforms. Also, isn't it true you cannot pass in more than one Entity to an API method? My Java code yells at me if I do saying you cannot have multiple Entity parameters.

Comment: It depends on what communication method you use, but the popular option is to pass entities as JSON. You can pass as many entities/properties as necessary, including lists of entities.

Comment: For the Android client I am using the auto generated Cloud Endpoints library that takes the App Engine project and creates a convenient Java library. I think there are some limitations there, and it certainly won't allow me to pass multiple entities.. I also found I cannot do something like `myPost.getUserKey()` if `@Parent private Key<User> userKey;` - Cloud Endpoints must restrict that or something. It yells at me when I try to create a getter/setter that is exposed to the API. I should have been clearer on how I am using Cloud Endpoints + Google App Engine + iOS/Android.

Comment: Those are two separate issues. You can easily pass multiple entities if you create a `class WrapperAB{A a;B b;}`. And yes cloud endpoints will not serialize `Ref` because it doesn't know how. An easy fix for that is to create a Getter and Setter for the id of the `Ref` with type `Long`/`String`. `public Long getAId(){return a.getKey().getId();}public void setAId(Long id){a=Key.create(A.class, id);}` - Uhm or i'm mixing jersey and clound endpoints again, in which case you could have to register a custom transformer.

Comment: Link to custom transformer doc: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#sample_endpoints_transformer_class

Comment: @konqi Indeed. This is a very interesting conversation I wish we were able to have in person. The thing is though, for me, my clients are iOS/Android. It is just much more convenient to store the `websafeKey` of an Entity that has a parent (such as `Post`). Then in my client, I can easily do `myPost.getWebsafeKey();` and pass that into the API method. It saves me having to generate the Key of the `Post` inside my client code. For Entities with no parents, I can just `User.getId()` and pass that into my API method (and generate the key inside the method).

Comment: @konqi The first bullet point of the accepted answer here illustrates me point as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811061/appengine-id-name-vs-websafekey

Comment: @MicroR I understand and I'm not saying that you shouldn't use websafe keys; just making you aware of possible drawbacks. Choose an approach and work with it. If it doesn't fly, change it. There are many possible solutions and it's very opinionated what the best solution is. It would go way too far to discuss all pros and cons here. Maybe someone should create a self-answered question some time to do exactly that. (Your lucky we don't have this discussion in person - i'm not very patient ;-)) Anyway, I hope all this back and forth will help you design a great API. Be seein' you around.

Comment: @konqi All this back and forth has definitely helped me see things from different perspectives and has certainly been helpful towards designing my API! =D

Answer (score 2):

When you use the autogenerated ids (ie Long), GAE uses the 'scattered' id generator which gives you ids from a broad range of the keyspace. This is because high volume writing (thousands per second) of more-or-less contiguous values in an index results in a lot of table splitting, hurting performance.

When you use `allocateId()`, you get an id from the older allocator that was used before scattered ids. They aren't necessarily contiguous or monotonic but they tend to start small and grow.

You can mix and match; allocations will never conflict.

I presume, however, that you want random-looking ids because you want them to be hard to guess. Despite their appearance at first glance, the scattered id allocator does not produce unguessable ids. If you want sparse ids that will prevent someone from scanning your keyspace, you need to explicitly add a random element. Or just use UUID.randomUUID() in the first place.

Comment: `UUID.randomUUID()` sounds like a good solution! Although my ID's would have to now be `String` instead of `Long` which I assume would be a bit more information to pass around? Maybe it doesn't matter anymore with mobile network speeds.

Comment: @MicroR - Everything you pass to a client is a string.